# Latex Equation and bmatrix

Tags: latex

I'm trying to use official equation, and it's giving me some trouble. I have this equation of a simple matrix operation, and LaTeX isn't liking it. What's wrong with this statement?

```
\begin{equation}
$M=\begin{bmatrix}
V_{1,1} & . & . & V_{1,n}\\ 
. & . &  & \\   
. &  &.  & \\ 
 V_{m,1}&  &  & V_{m,n}
\end{bmatrix}$
\end{equation}
```

The error is:
! Display math should end with $$.
 
                   M
l.186 $M
        =\begin{bmatrix}
? )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the two dollar signs:

```
\begin{equation}
M=\begin{bmatrix}
V_{1,1} & . & . & V_{1,n}\\ 
. & . &  & \\   
. &  &.  & \\ 
 V_{m,1}&  &  & V_{m,n}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 2):

Removing the two `$`s, you have no more error.

Then, you may want to use the commands `\cdots`, `\vdots`, `\ddots` available from LaTeX (package [`amsmath`](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) is not even necessary for these three, while it is required for environment `bmatrix`):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
M=\begin{bmatrix}
V_{1,1} & \cdots & V_{1,n}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
V_{m,1} & \cdots & V_{m,n}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image: screenshot of output]

(numbered `equation`). Notice how this is a 3-x-3 matrix, not 4-x-4.